# AllowDrop in AutoCompleteBox in WPF does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, uicontrol

I have a AutoCompleteBox control in my wpf application. I do not want to allow a value drop in it. I have bound AllowDrop=False but still I am able to drop values on it. Same is working very fine for my textbox. Can some one help.

here is my code:

```
<Control:AutoCompleteBox
     Name="selectCountry"
     Grid.Row="2"
     Grid.Column="1"
     Height="22"
     MinWidth="80"
     MaxWidth="80"
     FilterMode="Contains"
     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
     IsEnabled="{Binding xxx}"
     ItemsSource="{Binding xxx}"
     SelectedItem="{Binding xxx, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
     Text="{Binding xxx}"
     ValueMemberPath="xx"
     AllowDrop="False"                                      
>
```

Comment: whats is the baseclass of autocomplete and could you show us your control template ?

Comment: base class is clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls

Comment: edit your question with control template, if that's possible

Comment: I have not implemented any template. I am using default

Comment: you haven't defined anything in theme/generic file  for this autocomplete?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/599954/WPF-TemplateBinding-with-ControlTemplate

this may help

Comment: Are you sure AllowDrop is not getting set to true somewhere else (eg code behind?) Can you check at runtime using WPFInspector or Snoop? Are you sure there is not some other element over/under it that is accepting the drop?